# how to delete a file from git-repo from folder ignored by git

Tags: git

How can I delete a file from git if it is inside a folder marked to be ignored by git. For example - `/target/some_old_file.txt` was pushed to git before `target` was added in `.gitignore`

is it possible without modifying the .gitignore file.

Comment: do you mean delete from git repo or delete from file system?

Comment: delete it from git repo,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

To delete a file from git repo, you need to use

```
git rm --cached path/to/your/file
```

This means that git essentially forgets about the file in question.
Please make sure to use --cached flag. Without the flag, the file will also be deleted from file system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `target` folder from `.gitignore`
2. Remove the file and commit
3. Change the `.gitignore` to ignore the `target` folder again.